# Using PrimeNG's flexgrid in Angular 7 does not have any effect

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I want to use PrimeNG's [FlexGrid](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/flexgrid) and tried to simply copy the example:

```
<div class="p-grid">
    <div class="p-col">1</div>
    <div class="p-col">2</div>
    <div class="p-col">3</div>
</div>
```

which was supposed to output the numbers `1 2 3` next to each other. Sadly it does not, but just output:

```
1
2
3
```

I am able to use PrimeNG's Button-styles. Yet, I ensured I imported the css-files mentioned in the [Get-Started Guide](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup). In my `app.module.ts` it says:

```
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.css",
          "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
          "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css",
          "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css"
        ],
```

so these seem to be there. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install the `primeflex` package.

```
npm i primeflex
```

Then add the following to the styles array in your *angular.json* file.

```
node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.css
```

Things should work as expected afterward.

Comment: Do we need to add anything extra to get the background colors?

Answer (score 0):

You should run:

```
npm install primeflex --save
```

And add `primeflex.css` into your application

Inside `angular.json` file:

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.css"
],
```

After that run the app again and check if css class properties are  loading inside the app like below:
[image]